# Convert string file name to FormFile in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, .net-6.0, iformfile

I'm designing a web app using .net6 that contains a model and a view model like this:

```
public class Course
{
        public string CourseImageName { get; set; }
        public string DemoFileName { get; set; }
}

public class EditCourseViewModel
{
       public IFormFile CourseImageName { get; set; }
       public IFormFile DemoFileName { get; set; }
}
```

Create course is done successfully but in case of edit course when preview data, `CourseImageName` and `DemoFileName` in the model class that are string, should convert to `IFormFile` to show and then in case of any change of images save in database. how string file name can be convert to `IFormFile` for show as preview?

I need to find a way to convert string file name to `IFormFile`.

Comment: Why do you have `IFormFile` in your model? Do you use it for get and post?

Comment: How do you store the actual image? On disk? In the database?

Comment: I'm using SQLServer to store data and IFormFile.FileName will be post to database while images will store in server.

Answer (score 3):

[`IFormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-8.0) as docs claim:

> Represents a file sent with the `HttpRequest`.

And should not be used in the model to get data.

> how string file name can be convert to IFormFile for show as preview?

You should use the filename to build URL for the image and return it to the frontend.

Based on how you store the image on server you can either setup the middleware to [serve static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or create your own action which will return the file (for example via [`ControllerBase.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method).